# Security Concerns with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, security, http-headers

After reading a Wikipedia article about URL redirection I'm wondering if `window.location.href="page.php"` is the best option for a web page redirect. The wikipedia article suggests that

> However, HTTP headers or the refresh meta tag may be preferred for security reasons and because JavaScript will not be executed by some browsers and many web crawlers.

Is there anything I have to worry about? What could be some alternatives using javascipt if there is a problem? The window.location.href is activated when the user logs in.

Comment: This is probably the page that wasn't cited: http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246981/URL%20Redirector%20Abuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should aim at making your login page work without requiring JavaScript to make it more accessible from any device; you can make the user experience nicer with JavaScript by doing client-side checks, but those have to be made on the server anyway. It's quite common to do graceful degradation this way, allowing the lowest common denominator.

Having said that, if you're already using JavaScript to perform your login, it's obviously enabled and therefore redirection shouldn't be a problem at all. Without specific references I wouldn't be able to tell what security concerns that article is talking about.

Comment: I'm using jQuery ajax to check the username, password, security stuff, etc. so taking out JS is a no go. Thanks for your help. If no one responds in a day or two I'll give you the answer.

Comment: @jason328 Checks should be done on the server side as well. And I'm not saying to take JavaScript out, merely saying that you should think about making it possible to perform a login without relying on JavaScript, i.e. graceful degradation.

Comment: I'm curious, how would I determine when to not use JS? I would assume (whether right or wrong) that almost all users have and use JS.

Comment: @jason328 Again, I'm not saying you shouldn't use JavaScript; I'm saying that you should use it to *enhance* the experience, not make it dependent on JavaScript. Unless of course the rest of the site is completely useless without it :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess becoming dependent on AJAX has weakened my website in that regards. I will ponder over this.

Answer (score 1):

This way of redirecting only has security implications if you take the value of the page to redirect to from user input. If it is hardcoded, no problems.